# Can URLClassPath be used thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I was messing around with loading classes async using URLClassLoader, turns out that it is not thread safe because what it calls to find the class file itself (URLClassPath) doesn't work async.
Example:
Here is the URLClassPath on the main thread for class loading:
Code:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL("jar:file:Drive:\path-to-jar\MyJar.jar!/org/example/Example.class")};
URLClassPath ucp = new URLClassPath(urls);
String path = "org/example/Example.class";
System.out.println("Resource (" + path + ") : " +ucp.loadResource(path));
```

```
Resource (org/example/Example.class): jar:file:Drive:\path-to-jar\MyJar.jar!/org/example/Example.class
```

Now, I use a cache'd executor service to call the same method for loading external classes from a jar. I set the thread loader of the executor thread to the URLClassLoader:

```
Resource (org/example/Example.class): null
```

I tried making a new instance of the URLClassLoader on every thread, but the problem is, I have no clue what ClassLoader to use. The class's class loader gives the same error, and the Thread's context class loader just freezes the thread.

So, now the only things I can think of doing:
 1. Making every call to URLClassLoader#loadClass(String) run on the same thread it was created on, the problem is that is a huge bottleneck
 2. Somehow getting the resource, and passing it to the ClassLoader to make the definition.
 3. Somehow making it thread safe.

But again, I have no clue why it is not thread safe in the first place.

Any ideas on either why it isn't thread safe, or how to make it thread safe?

Comment: `Resource (org/example/Example.class): null` ← What is that?  What code generated that?  I think it came from something like `System.out.println("Resource (org/example/Example.class): " + myUrlClassLoader.getResource("org/example/Example.class"));` but it’s not clear from your description.  Considering adding code that comprises a [mre] to your question;  code is usually easier to understand than an abstract description of code.

Comment: I forgot to include my code... fixed it, sorry for the stupidity @VGR

Comment: Class-loading is threadsafe in general, so this should be no exception. But your URL string is invalid. It must use forward slashes. Surprised this even compiles. Does it really?

Comment: What is the `URLClassPath` class?  It’s not `sun.misc.URLClassPath`, is it?  Under no circumstances should any program access any sun.* package.  If you have code that makes use of URLClassLoader, please include that code in your question.

Comment: It's under the package jdk.internal.loader, and I'm using it through URLClassLoader, but I know the problem is with URLClassPath, not URLClassLoader.

Comment: ClassLoaders are designed to be thread-safe.  If you’re hacking into things like URLClassPath, you are risking problems.  (The compiler should be giving you a warning that sun.* classes are not safe to use.)  If you stick to just using URLClassLoader, you should not have any problems with thread safety.

Comment: I am using URLClassLoader, and it's still not thread safe unless I create a new instance on every thread, because of URLClassPath.